# Gradle Intelli J Error "org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed"

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Beginner Programmer here. It's my first time testing how to use gradle in Intelli J so I downloaded gradle zip and set up the environment variables. After I went to try and use it on Intelli J it gave me this error code "org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed" I have no I idea what could be wrong or the error itself. But Java itself is working fine, I wanted to test gradle but I don't know how to troubleshoot it I've searched for the internet and showed only how to do it on Android but an Intelli J has different option.

In summary:
How to resolve Gradle "org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed" in Intelli J-IDEA

Screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quiLR.png)

Comment: Make sure you use compatible Gradle version (set in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file) and Gradle JDK (se in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Gradle JVM**): https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

Comment: Also, the `build.gradle` file looks empty - does not have any build configuration for Java. Better use IntelliJ IDEA new project wizard to create a new Gradle Java project.

Comment: @Andrey I clicked Intelli J IDEA new poject from main menu while creating files it failed to build showing the error. Also I am using jdk 17 and latest gradle. Where can I find gradle-wrapper.properties?

Comment: gradle init is also working